# Different versions of the same gem in Gemfile - possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have 2 gems:

```
gem 'A'
gem 'B'
gem 'C'

gem 'X'
```

gems A, B and C has a dependency which is gem X. gem X just **happens** to be in Gemfile, not in Gemfile.lock, because it itself is used throughout an application.

However, A and B (and other gems, in fact) need the version 1 of X, whereas C and only C needs the version2. How can I make them use **different** version of X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It is disallowed in bundler

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can specify call of `gem 'X', '1'` in ruby file, but this approach is strongly NOT RECOMMENDED, cause introduces clashes as described above.

Answer (score 0):

That will probably will not work. Anyway... how would you expect that your A & B gems use the version 1 from the X gem, and C the version 2?

Another thing is, if version 1 is defining a class, and version 2 is defining the same class, but overriding v1 methods, then the "final class code" will depend on the load order.